# Why does enabling word wrap for a QLabel alter the layout?

Tags: qt, pyside, qlabel

So i have a small program i've made with Qt Designer, and for the most part, it's completely fine. But there is one niggling problem;

I have a `QLabel`, for which the text is sometimes too long, so i want to make the text wrap. This should be a simple task.

Here is what it looks like with *no wordwrap*

[image]

And this is fine. But when the text gets too long, it puts in a horrible scroll bar. I don't want this, so i enable wordwrap. But then this happens:

[image]

Which at first i thought was just Qt Designer being crap, so compiled and run hoping it would go away. Sometimes this happens, so i thought it was a reasonable assumption.

It wasn't.

[image]

**Why the hell is this happening?!**

EDIT: enabling word wrap manually in the widget initialiser also causes the same behaviour - so it's not caused by Qt Designer, it's an issue elsewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the content of the UI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>705</width>
    <height>347</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Title</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset resource="icons.qrc">
    <normaloff>:/icons/icons/3/bonus48x48_20.png</normaloff>:/icons/icons/3/bonus48x48_20.png</iconset>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" columnstretch="0,1,1">
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_molecule">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Molecule:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_molecule"/>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QToolBox" name="toolBox_modelDetails">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_isomer">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>373</width>
         <height>154</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <attribute name="label">
        <string>Isomer</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_isomers">
          <property name="alternatingRowColors">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_model">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>357</width>
         <height>231</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <attribute name="label">
        <string>Model</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2" stretch="0,0">
        <item>
         <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_models">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <stylestrategy>PreferDefault</stylestrategy>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="lineWidth">
           <number>1</number>
          </property>
          <property name="alternatingRowColors">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label_description">
          <property name="text">
           <string>Howdy!</string>
          </property>
          <property name="wordWrap">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="page_basisSet">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>373</width>
         <height>154</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <attribute name="label">
        <string>Basis Set</string>
       </attribute>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
        <item>
         <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget_basisSets">
          <property name="alternatingRowColors">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0" colspan="3">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_buttons">
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_buttons">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_save">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Save Input File</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_open">
        <property name="text">
         <string>Open</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2" rowspan="2">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox_MoleculeViewer">
      <property name="title">
       <string>Molecule</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="icons.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I don't understand... Is your problem related to ListView? Try to improve ListView minimum size and size policy. Or... please, provide a sample code which will reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Where is that outer scrollbar coming from?

Comment: Please post the UI file contents.

Comment: I'll post the ui file later, when i boot into unix.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld the inner scroll bar is for the list view, the outer list view is the toolbox. I'd rather just have a scroll bar in the list view, and set it's size to make it all fit in the toolbox page.

Comment: @Riatche - There you go.

Answer (score 2):

QLabel in combination with word wrap and Layouts give some funny behaviour. 
See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37673.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you nesting your widgets (the `QLabel` and the `QListWidget`) into a `QWidget`?

That's why you are getting two scrollbars. One from the `QListWidget`, because it has more items than can be viewed. And one for the parent `QWidget`.

You should be using [layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html).

This is what you have:

[image]

Should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: the "widget" it's nested inside is the page of the QToolBox.